# How to share my GAE app to other people?

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot find real URL for my GAE app. Mine url on my browser is https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=helloworldjack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://helloworldjack.appspot.com